# Sort by variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I want code to figure how large a table of data is, then sort it. I assumed that I would declare a variable range once I knew how large the table is and tell Excel to sort first by the variable range "Account" and then "Symbol" and then "Quantity."

The problem occurs with the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Account")...`

Method *Range of Object' Global Failed* is my error message. It appears that this is not the correct way to give it a variable range.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
Sub Macro1()
     '
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mutual Funds").Activate
Range("A12").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select


 Dim Account As Range
 Dim Symbol As Range
 Dim Quantity As Range
 Dim EntireRange As Range

 Set Account = Range(ActiveCell, "A11")
 Set Symbol = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(, 9), "J11")
 Set Quantity = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(, 7), "H11")
 Set EntireRange = Range(ActiveCell, "AS11")

 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Account"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Symbol"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Quantity"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").Sort
    .SetRange Range("EntireRange")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: What you could use is ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mutual Funds").UsedRange.Address to determine how big the data is. I am guessing that you only need one range and want to sort all the data by something. Why do you specify multiple ranges? Do you need to sort by more than one vale?

Comment: I was hoping to do a multi level sort. So that it would sort by column A first and formost, but then if there were duplicates, it would also sort column J, and then column H

Comment: I don't believe the sort function works like that unless you are willing to ignore the data next to column A. For example if cell A1 has "this" in it and B1 has "that" in it A2 has "A" in it and B2 has "Z" in it. If you sort by column A ascending and do not include B column it will have "A" in cell A1 and "this" in cell A2. The B column will remain unchanged. Is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Range("Account")` to reference a `Range` variable is wrong.

Just use `Account`

Other issues:

- The `Key`'s need to exclude the header,
- Your method of getting the used ranges is highly inefficient.

Here's your code refactored :

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Account As Range
    Dim Symbol As Range
    Dim Quantity As Range
    Dim EntireRange As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mutual Funds")

    With ws
        Set Account = .Range(.Cells(12, 1), .Cells(12, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With
    Set Symbol = Account.Offset(, 8)
    Set Quantity = Account.Offset(, 6)
    Set EntireRange = Account.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(Account.Rows.Count + 1, 45)

    With ws.Sort ' EntireRange
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Account, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Symbol, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Quantity, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange EntireRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```